# Will Delete SQL locks the table which prevents new data insert into SQL Server 2005?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

If I try to delete a brunch of data from a table. say

```
DELETE FROM myTable Where CreationDate < GetDate()
```

that takes hours to be deleted, will this table be locked and no new insert can happened?

This table doesn't self reference itself. I would assume I can still insert new data while it is deleting. Will the delete sql uses an exclusive lock that prevents all access to the table?

Thanks

Comment: Removed my answer - I read too quickly and assumed we were talking about `SELECT` during a `DELETE`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can batch them to prevent it from locking the whole table:

```
WHILE 1 = 1
  BEGIN
        DELETE  TOP 10000 FROM  myTable WHERE CreationDate < GetDate()

        IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0
            BREAK
  END
```

Comment: 10K rows will escalate to table lock. Keep it under 5K to prevent this.

Comment: The number of locks required for an escalation is not strictly 5K. There are several other factors around it. The following does a decent job of explaining it for SQL 2005: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlserverstorageengine/archive/2006/05/17/lock-escalation.aspx

Comment: The critical thing is though to have an index on CreationDate. W/o it a table scan is required for each batch.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of things that could change this behavior. However, if by a lot you mean over 5K records than it will probably lock. You can avoid this by using smaller batches or specifying an isolation level that will not lock.

Comment: You can't "specify an isolation level that will not lock." as the OP is asking about `deletes` and `inserts`. These will always take locks.